# Google sheets - create a pivot table from two different sheets (income, expenses)

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, report

I want to create a pivot table, or a report from two different G.Sheet sheets. One is income sheet, and other is expenses. On both sheets there is a same category with the same data validation (name of the project).

What I am trying to get is a pivot table, or some kind of report that would calculate the difference between incomes and expenses for each project, like:

[image: The result should be this]

The link to the sample document is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VmI3UWRotL_zxNiwbQRDWQaaSp7c-2Ilafu6xjv9qMI/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one `formula-based` approach which you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ;unique(tocol({Expenses!G2:G;Income!F2:F};1));
     sort(hstack(Σ;index(sumif(Income!F:F;Σ;Income!D:D)-sumif(Expenses!G:G;Σ;Expenses!E:E)));2;))
```

[image]

Comment: That works neatly. Thank you very much for the formula!

Answer (score 0):

Hii Follow this to generate the pivot of your choice :

two things you need to do

1. Keep the project column in row of pivot table
   and
2. keep the amount at the value and also make sure the function being used is SUM

Attached a screenshot of the configuration below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOBfg.png)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the quick response! This would sum just the expenses, or the income... What I am trying to get is in a single table the balance between incomes and expenses for each project.